# Scala 3 type class fails: given_... is already defined in scope as class

Tags: scala, typeclass, implicit, scala-3

If I try to compile the following code in Scala 3, I get a `given_Finder_Needle_*: is already defined as class given_Finder_Needle_*`

Am I doing something wrong? Is this the right way of implementing type classes in Scala?

```scala
trait Finder[Needle, Haystack]:
  def get: Needle

given[Needle, Tail <: Tuple]: Finder[Needle, Needle *: Tail] with
  def get: Needle = ???

given[Needle, Head, Tail <: Tuple] (using finder: Finder[Needle, Tail]): Finder[Needle, Head *: Tail] with
  def get: Needle = finder.get
```

Comment: It seems the compiler is generating the same name to both `given` why don't you give them specific names?

Comment: right, exactly. how do I give a name to a `given`? @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez

Comment: `given whatEverName: Type with`

Comment: right, that works yes. although there's no real reason why I should worry about different names here, the compiler should just do a better job at generating a unique class name

Comment: For library authors it's recommend to give a name anyway to help binary compatibility